# Making a working fighting system for enemies

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to make a fight button that make enemy take damage. then it increases kill count for later making the button disabled until a certain amount of kills of a monster.
https://jsfiddle.net/7nbvaszh/9/   my fiddle its the bottom part . i have the enemy and hp nicely stacked. I should also add that the player should lose hp equal to the enemy's damage on click to so basically fight button when rat is on 1 damage( this will be different made it one just to get it to work) so it should have 9 hp after first click and player should have 9 hp( u can make a variable for hp and make it 10 its 0 atm because i wanted hp unlocked later but just for testing purposes it can be added)

My friend and i tried this but  its not working

```
var currentEnemyName;
 var currentEnemyHp;

var hasEnemyToFight = false;

var enemyNames = ["rat     ","slime   ","goblin  ","skeleton","zombie  ","succubus"]
var enemyHps = [10,20,25,50,75,100]
var enemyStrengths = [1,3,5,10,15,25]

var currentItemIndex = 0;


  var ratKills = 0;
  var slimeKills = 0;
  var goblinKills = 0;
  var skeletonKills = 0;
  var zombieKills = 0;
  var succubusKills = 0;
  var Strength = 1;

  document.getElementById("enemyHp").innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById("enemyName").innerHTML="None";

 function spawnNewEnemy(enemyNum){
   currentEnemyName = enemyNames[enemyNum];
  currentEnemyHp = enemyHps[enemyNum];

  hasEnemyToFight = true;

  document.getElementById("enemyHp").innerHTML=currentEnemyHp;
  document.getElementById("enemyName").innerHTML=currentEnemyName;
  }


    function fight(){

 if(hasEnemyToFight == false){
 spawnNewEnemy(currentItemIndex)
 document.getElementById("enemyName").innerHTML=currentEnemyName+" appeared!";
 }

 else{

    if(currentEnemyHp > 0){
        currentEnemyHp -= 1;
    document.getElementById("enemyHp").innerHTML=currentEnemyHp;

    if (currentEnemyHp <=0){
        currentEnemyHp = 0;
        goldcoins += 10;

        hasEnemyToFight = false;

        if(enemyName == "rat"){
        ratKills++
        }
        else if(enemyName == "skeleton"){
        skeletonKills++
        }


        }
}

    document.getElementById("enemyHp").innerHTML=currentEnemyHp;
    document.getElementById("enemyName").innerHTML=currentEnemyName;
    document.getElementById("goldcoins").innerHTML=goldCoins;


}
```

Javascript for my working code:

```
 function show() { 
    var enemy = enemyName[currentItemIndex];
    var enemyHitPoints = enemyHp[currentItemIndex];

document.getElementById("enemyName").innerHTML=enemyName[currentItemIndex]
    document.getElementById("enemyHp").innerHTML=enemyHp[currentItemIndex]
    document.getElementById("previous").disabled=currentItemIndex<=0;




   document.getElementById("next").disabled 
  =currentItemIndex>=enemyName.length- 
  1;

}

   var enemyName = ["rat     ","slime   ","goblin  ","skeleton","zombie  
","succubus"]
var enemyHp = [10,20,25,50,75,100]
var enemyStrength = [1,3,5,10,15,25]

var currentItemIndex = 0;




window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("previous").onclick=function() {
    currentItemIndex--;
    if (currentItemIndex<=0) {
      currentItemIndex=0;
    }
    show();       
  }
  document.getElementById("next").onclick=function() {
    currentItemIndex++;
    if (currentItemIndex>=enemyName.length-1) {
      currentItemIndex=enemyName.length-1;
    }
    show();       
  }


  var ratKills = 0;
  var slimeKills = 0;
  var goblinKills = 0;
  var skeletonKills = 0;
 var zombieKills = 0;
var succubusKills = 0;
var Strength = 1;


function fight(){
    if(enemyName == "rat" && enemyHp > 0)
        enemyHp = enemyHp - Strength;
    document.getElementById("enemyHp").innerHTML=enemyHp;
    if (enemyHp <=0)
        enemyHp = 0;
        goldcoins = goldcoins +10;
    document.getElementById("enemyHp").innerHTML=enemyHp;
    document.getElementById("goldcoins").innerHTML=enemyHp;


}






}
```

html:

```
 <button onclick="fight()" id="Fightbtn" >Fight</button> <span 
id="enemyName">rat</span>  &nbsp; Hp:<span id="enemyHp">10</span>
                <body>

 <style>
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.previous {
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

.next {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.round {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>                   


<a href="#" id="previous" class="previous round">&#8249;</a>
<a href="#" id="next" class="next round">&#8250;</a>

        </body>
```

I expect when you press the fight button for the enemys hp to go down by how much strength you have then once hp goes below 0 for 10 gold to be given then the enemy's hp to reset back to 10. but at the moment the fight button isnt doing anything and the enemy's hp is not going down. the players hp should also go down by 1 or whatever that enemys damage is. im sure there is a simple solution im missing to making my if statements work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice! This is a good start for having some fun while learning javascript.

The main reasons your fiddle was broken:

1. There were multiple `html`, `head` and `body` tags. A document should only have one of each of these.
2. The script that had your code was after the closing `</html>` tag, so the browser didn't even execute it.
3. The `fight` function (as well as a large number of important variables) was declared inside of a `window.onload` function, so you couldn't call it from your button.

Once all of that is resolved, the `fight` function itself needs to point to the hp of the current enemy. As it stands, it will replace the array that holds all of the enemy hp information.

[Here's an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8js6o1v9/) the fixes the top 3 and points the fight function values to the right places.

This shows the script contents from the updated fiddle, which is a working sketch of how this could be approached:

```
var enemyName = ["rat", "slime", "goblin", "skeleton", "zombie", "succubus"]
var enemyHp = [10, 20, 25, 50, 75, 100]
var enemyStrength = [1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 25]
var enemyIsDead = false
var currentItemIndex = 0;
var goldcoins = 0
var enemy
var enemyHitPoints

var ratKills
var slimeKills
var goblinKills
var skeletonKills
var zombieKills
var succubusKills
var Strength

function show() {
  enemy = enemyName[currentItemIndex];
  enemyHitPoints = enemyHp[currentItemIndex];
  enemyIsDead = false
  document.getElementById("enemyName").innerHTML = enemyName[currentItemIndex]
  document.getElementById("enemyHp").innerHTML = enemyHp[currentItemIndex]
  document.getElementById("previous").disabled = currentItemIndex <= 0;
  document.getElementById("next").disabled = currentItemIndex >= enemyName.length - 1;
}


function fight() {
  if (enemyHitPoints > 0) {
    enemyHitPoints = enemyHitPoints - Strength;
    document.getElementById("enemyHp").innerHTML = enemyHitPoints;
  } else if (!enemyIsDead) {
    enemyHitPoints = 0;
    enemyIsDead = true
    goldcoins += 10;
    document.getElementById("enemyHp").innerHTML = enemyHitPoints;
    document.getElementById("goldcoins").innerHTML = goldcoins;
  }
}

window.onload = function () {
  ratKills = 0;
  slimeKills = 0;
  goblinKills = 0;
  skeletonKills = 0;
  zombieKills = 0;
  succubusKills = 0;
  Strength = 1;

  show()

  document.getElementById("previous").onclick = function () {
    currentItemIndex--;
    if (currentItemIndex <= 0) {
      currentItemIndex = 0;
    }
    show();
  }

  document.getElementById("next").onclick = function () {
    currentItemIndex++;
    if (currentItemIndex >= enemyName.length - 1) {
      currentItemIndex = enemyName.length - 1;
    }
    show();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks yea im not perfect at html yet. my whole game has been working so far and i keep adding more parts . im just missing having disabled tabs under conditions and i wanted this system. thank you so much

Comment: is there a way to make diffrent rewards for diffrent enemys? like i wanted to eventaully make it so you need 10 rat kills to be able to move on to next enemy and the next enemy should give more of a gold reward.   something like   if(enemyName == "rat" && enemyHp < 0)    goldcoins = goldcoins +10;

Comment: ratkills=ratkills +1 and then i decided to just make hp 10 again when it goes to zero or below    so if slime is selected reward should be mroe gold and slime kills should go up and so on .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/exdu3zb0/16/   this but eatch enemy should increase there own counter and reward more gold if they are harder to kill

Comment: This will start to become difficult to keep track of in the current format. You'll probably want to move to a more object-based approach to get more control and reusability.

Comment: theres no easy way to do like if(index0 && enemyhp <0)

Comment: ratkills=ratkills+1                               goldcoins=goldcoins+10        if(index1 && enemyhp<0)      slimkills= slimkills+1                          goldcoins = goldcoins +15                        and so on

Comment: You can, but that means you need to track hp + kills + kill thresholds for each enemy. That will not scale well if you're tracking that all as loose variables. If you create a `monster` object that can accept configuration and has some defaults, this would get a lot simpler and easier to reason about.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fvxj5byu/7/ i got this working but when i add a thing to make enemys do damage  https://jsfiddle.net/ky3tg0j6/ it stops me from being able to change enemys